# Creating an array formula with an if statement that sums across multiple columns

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array

I need help making this an array. I think it might be a multi issue? When I create an array, it populates down the row, but only draws on the first row of columns.

=if(ISTEXT('2014 QAs'!E19), (if(100-sum(L20:AF20)<0, 0, (100-sum(L20:AF20))))," ")

Comment: Sounds like you may have calculation set to manual - press F9 to calculate or use "Calculation Options" on Formula tab to change to automatic. Perhaps also simplify formula with MAX, i.e. `=IF(ISTEXT('2014 QAs'!E19),MAX(0,100-SUM(L20:AF20)),"")`

Answer (score 0):

## Planning and Designing Array-Like Data Structures for Excel Formulas

Using the supplied formula, I was able to create a result column that could be "copied down" for all rows represented in a multi-record data set.

```
=if(ISTEXT('2014 QAs'!E19), (if(100-sum(L20:AF20)<0, 0, (100-sum(L20:AF20))))," ")
```

The solution to getting this formula above to work was to create sub-calculations.  This post used extra columns (See COLs G, H, I and J) to define parts of the overall expression in your conditional statement.  After breaking this complex expression down, the formula provided results.

[image: Alternate Sheet Reference Data]

This is the data put on `Sheet3` of the solution.  The expression: `ISTEXT('2014 QAs'!E19)` suggests that part of the formula includes a reference to an alternate page titled: `2014 QAs`, which I have just named `Sheet3`.

[image: Multiple Column Array-Styled Statement]

The formula of the OP works fine.  I suspect that Excel may have choked on the thick syntax of the expression.  Sometimes dividing out discrete unit calculations to simplify the expression helps.  The sub-calculations can simply be `HIDDEN` for a cleaner final presentation.

In answer to your question, the final formula consists of expressions divided into multiple parts:

```
=if(ISTEXT('2014 QAs'!E19), (if(100-sum(L20:AF20)<0, 0, (100-sum(L20:AF20))))," ")

Condenses Into...

Column J is
=IF(ISTEXT(Sheet3!A2), I2, " ")

Where...

Column G is
@SUM(A2:F2)

Column H is
= 100 - G2

Column I is
=(IF H2 < 0, 0, H2)
```

These formulas defined for Row ID = 2 can "copy down" to other rows as new instances of the same formula for each spreadsheet record.

Comment: My initial approach using named ranges was not enough.  Check out my revision.  It's simpler and also recognizes that Excel spreadsheet grids already behave like arrays.  `... it populates down the row, but only draws on the first row of columns.` shows that the OP just wants the same calculation to repeat for each row of data.

Comment: I am puzzled as well.  My first response addressed the tags (i.e., `multi-dimensional arrays`, `arrays`) by building arrays of values through defining `named ranges` in excel. This last response addresses the actual formula from the OP but as you noted, the real issue is probably a small mistake in syntax vs. a large paradigm shift in MS Excel design concepts.  Thanks for your comments though, @pnuts.  I'm still unclear on what the real problem is with this post.